# C# Windows10 Shortcut for Startup (through InstallShield or Coding) for AllUsers

Tags: c#, windows-10, shortcut

Through Install Shield (Registry Setting for startup ) 
and also from the code below both were creating shortcut which were running just fine before Windows 10 version but the shortcut is not executing and throwing error, seems to be Windows 10 issue for Shortcut. How to create shortcut specifically for Windows 10 with Admin rights

```
   static void ApplicationShortCut(string shortcutName)
    {
        string startUpFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        string shortcutLocation = Path.Combine(startUpFolderPath, shortcutName + ".lnk");
        if (!Directory.Exists(startUpFolderPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(startUpFolderPath);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(shortcutLocation))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(shortcutLocation);
        }

        WshShell shell = new WshShell();
        IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);
        shortcut.Description = "Program Desc";
        shortcut.TargetPath = @"C:\Program Files\Folder\ProgramName.exe";
        shortcut.Save();

    }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: FWIW, I copy/pasted your code and it works fine on my side. I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Yes Sorceri its strange for some machines it works here too :( , still not figure out whats the case, thats why I want to make sure Shortcut with Admin Rights probably thats the only difference possible

Answer (score 1):

Don't accept this as answer. Just posting so you see exactly what I used in order to claim it worked on my end.

The shortcut works if I manually double-click it.
The shortcut also works if I restart my machine. AKA the program linked to the shortcut starts on its own when the machine boots up.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

namespace MakingShortcutsInWindows10_46837557
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationShortCut(@"C:\Program Files\EditPlus\editplus.exe", "BlahBlahDesc", "MakeItThisName");
        }

        static void ApplicationShortCut(string shortcutPath, string shortcutDescription, string shortcutName)
        {
            string startUpFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
            string shortcutLocation = Path.Combine(startUpFolderPath, shortcutName + ".lnk");
            if (!Directory.Exists(startUpFolderPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(startUpFolderPath);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(shortcutLocation))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(shortcutLocation);
            }

            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);
            shortcut.Description = shortcutDescription;
            shortcut.TargetPath = shortcutPath;
            shortcut.Save();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My code is doing the same , the code snippet I created here is just for example. it throws error in Windows 10 Professional, I found shortcut.lnk is not just the Text file in Windows 10 but had some encrypted values, thats not happening with this method

Comment: Works for me on Win 10. But it needs a reference added: "Project > Add Reference > COM > Windows Script Host Object Model". Also using `Application.ExecutablePath` is a good way to get the path of the currently open executable, so you can create a shortcut of it.